# How to clear the URL_GET after clicking hyperlink

Tags: php, get

When I press a hyperlink

```
<.a href="template_edit.php?templateId=...&bbId=...&editReq=...">  
  <.img src="...">  
<./a>
```

It will refresh the page cuz I was already on 'template_edit.php?templateId=...'
But when the refresh is done and the query has been updated succesfull I want that the $_GET['bbId'] and the $_GET['editReq'] will get deleted without refreshing the page again.

I hope you guys can help me with this.
If you need more information to help me, say it please.

Thankz.

[EDIT-1]
Steps:
1: I have the hyperlink that is filled with a link to a page with 3 GET's in it.

2: Then it refresh the page cuz it is already on that page en the URL GET's are filled in.

3: Then when the query that will update things in the DB is done succesfully it     needs to delete 2 GET's of the 3   GET's without refresh the page!

[EDIT-2]
Some more information maybe handy.
The code what i have till now is this.

```
//This is the update query
if (!empty($_GET['editReq'])) {
  mysql_query("
    UPDATE formbbformtemplate
    SET formRequired = '".$_GET['editReq']."'
    WHERE formTemplateId = ".$_GET['templateId']."
    AND formBuildingBlockId = ".$_GET['bbId']."
  ") or die(__LINE__.": ".mysql_error());
}

//The hyperlink / image button.
<a href="template_edit.php?templateId=<?=$templateId?>&bbId=<?=$vragen['formBuildingBlockId']?>&editReq=off">
  <img style="opacity: .25;" src="<?=IMG?>/cross.png" title="Niet Verplicht!">
</a>

//Below here there needs to come the SCRIPT
<script>
  //script
</script>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should redirect to the page without the query string. Look into PHP's `header` function. You really should be POSTing form data though

Comment: Can you describe step by step  what you want to achive? It's kind of hard to follow.

Comment: @Jonathon No I need to do it when I click on the image so i have to do it with  <a> but when I click it needs to be put in the $_GET and when the query has done his things it needs to clear the $_GET without refresh the page!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Oke i will put it in edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via jquery on your `template_edit.php` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  if(url.indexOf('&') !== -1) //This will check if the url contains more than 1 GET.
  {
   url = url.slice( 0, url.indexOf('&') ); // This will keep the first GET 
   window.location.href = url;
  }
});
```

Comment: By me it doesn't work. IDK what I do wrong. What I did was  just add it in the script. tag

Comment: you have jQuery included ?

Comment: You have to learn what jquery is before using jQuery code. 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
Put this line at in your `<head>` tags.

Comment: I have this: `<script src="/Stage/ComputerTraining.nl/_inc/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
           `<script src="/Stage/ComputerTraining.nl/_inc/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: see the updated part. This way you'll know if jQuery is loaded. If it is you will get the alert box. If you don't get see the browser console if there are any errors popping up.

Comment: Please post the complete code of your template file in the question. You might doing some thing silly i have a feeling :)

Comment: Oke dont blame me it isnt my code but the one of my boss... i do it in a new Answer!

Comment: so if you see in your answer the script i sent to you above is placed outside the `$(document).ready()`. I changed the position of script in your answer may be you'll see once its peer reviewed.

Comment: Eeh i tried but what it did it just cut 1 character everytime and refreshed!?

Comment: yes because there is a mistake every time page get loaded my script runs and force to be refereshed. You need to do some code to check if its a one time refreshed.

Comment: @Lenap paste the script now. I provided in the answer above. Basically its a rough trick that i check if there is more than 1 GET (Means anything after the `templateId` than do the trick otherwise let the page load as it is).

Comment: Now i used what you gave me. only i changed `if(url.indexOf('&') === -1)` to `if(url.indexOf('&') !== -1)`.. But now it still refreshing! I need to clear it but not refresh the page!

Comment: Cool answer, it took a me while to comprehend it as I'm quite new when it comes to using PHP. In any case looks really useful :-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you for example check in your php code if the page request is initial or a refresh one (following your hyperlink click). Something like below:

```
//test for refresh 
if (isset($_GET['bbId']) && isset($_GET['editReq']) ) {
    //create your anchor tag here without 'bbId' and 'editReq'
  <a href="template_edit.php?templateId=<?=$templateId?>">
  <img style="opacity: .25;" src="<?=IMG?>/cross.png" title="Niet Verplicht!">
</a>

} // else initial page request
else {      
  //create your anchor tag here as usual
      //The hyperlink / image button.
<a href="template_edit.php?templateId=<?=$templateId?>&bbId=<?=$vragen['formBuildingBlockId']?>&editReq=off">
  <img style="opacity: .25;" src="<?=IMG?>/cross.png" title="Niet Verplicht!">
</a>
}
```

I haven't tested the above but it could work :-)

Comment: This is a much cleaner and pro approach

Comment: I dont realy get it what you mean here?

Comment: @Lenap I've added some code from your question to the if/else block, I hope it helps. Note I haven't tested the code.

Comment: @Lenap I'm quite new with PHP too, so at the moment I'm a bit of a PHP enthusiast, but the logic in the answer above, was picked up from this free e-book: Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript, 4th Edition by Robin Nixon. http://it-ebooks.info/book/4681/ Page 241. So I was thinking that there could be a similar logic when submitting some data (page 241 in the book) and your question. Well, I'm still learning :-)

Comment: @jyrkim Its not the same. but i did with the answer of Raheel Khan Check it out if you wanna learn about it.

Comment: @Lenap Cheers, it Raheel Khan's answer look great. I think now I get his answer - it took me a while to understand it but it's cool :-) So it's the page refresh you wan't to avoid, then jQuery .get() function will do the trick for you as well http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/, if you plan to use it then you need to make anchor elements that only call a function that has .get() method call inside it; so the anchor doesn't execute instead call the function for get() method call, but that's an alternative :-)